# Statistical functions (max, min, abs, ...) with linear operations

Tags: linear-transformations, maxima-minima

I came across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232585/crt-representation-of-integers-and-multiplication-in-almost-linear-time) question. It shows two nice formulas for finding max and min without comparison. I find the formulas beautiful because they do not use comparisons.

I am not sure whether my question is stated correctly, but I am interested in finding such nice formulas for maybe other functions as well such as abs, round, floor, truncate, sqrt ... etc

What is this area of mathematics called?
Could you provide pointers for related papers or books on this topic.

Comment: What you linked to is not a way to compute max and min with linear operations; it computes them with linear operations in combination with non-linear operations. In fact, the square root function is _required_ by the formulas you linked to; also those formulas already use square roots to compute absolute values. For the other functions you mention, you need something discontinuous to start with.

Comment: @DavidK Could you share some resources on this. I can't find the right keywords to google this. I find those formulas very interesting, and I want to learn more about them.